# Intellij not detecting code changes when building artifacts

Tags: java, intellij-idea

In Intellij IDE, in a Kotlin project, when I don't have any artifacts, everything is fine.
when I create an artifact and build it, Intellij is not running new code version (not detecting code changes when building and running the project), it is running already built artifact instead.
I have found out this after a lot of testing, also I do not mean it is actually running artifact, it is running the same code when artifact was built.
so I should run build artifacts each time before running the code normally, to see the result of changed code.

I have done invalidate cache and restart, installed latest version, created new project, changed jdk version...

Comment: What type of dependency/build tool do you use? Gradle, Maven?

Comment: I'm using Gradle

Comment: Does it help if you enable "Include in project build" option for the artifact?